# Python `cache` decorator only when DEBUG is False

Tags: python, python-decorators

I am trying to make a decorator that when `DEBUG == True`, it does not cache, but when `DEBUG == False`, then it does cache.

This is what I came up with. It works in the case when `DEBUG == False`. The issue is when `DEBUG == True`:

```py
from functools import lru_cache

DEBUG = True

def prod_lru_cache(*args, **kwargs):
    def no_decorator(func):
        return func

    if DEBUG:
        return no_decorator
    else:
        return prod_lru_cache(*args, **kwargs)
```

The issue is that `lru_cache` can take an optional argument `maxsize`.

If it takes no arguments, then I think the above is fine, e.g. We get back the original function as required when `DEBUG == False`:

```
DEBUG = False

@prod_lru_cache
def foo():
   print('foo')

# prod_lru_cache(foo) -> (return no_decorator) -> (return foo) -> foo
```

However if it does take an argument, then it does no work:

```
DEBUG = False

@prod_lru_cache(maxsize=7)
def foo():
   print('foo')

# prod_lru_cache(maxsize=7)(foo) -> (return no_decorator)(foo) -> (foo)foo -> ????
```

How does one handle both scenarios? I can't think of a way to distinguish between the passed in user function, and an arg (which in some cases could be a callable), in this example it should always be an int, but I would like to apply the same concept to other decorators.

A hack solution I came up with is:

```
def prod_cache(*args, **kwargs):
    def no_decorator(f):
        return f

    if settings.DEBUG:
        return args[0] if args and callable(args[0]) else no_decorator
    else:
        return cache(*args, **kwargs)
```

But it is not generic in that what if I wish to make a decorator with an arg that is a callable, then I can't apply the same logic.